# What's wrong in python script?

Tags: python, windows-xp, program-entry-point, indentation

What's wrong in python script?

Code:

```
import os    
import shutil
import getpass    
os.mkdir("C:\\dtmp") 

shutil.copy("C:\\path\\to\\bb-freeze-script.py","C:\\dtmp")
os.chdir("C:\\dtmp")
shutil.copy("C:\\path\\to\\main.py","C:\\dtmp")
os.system("python bb-freeze-script.py main.py")

os.mkdir("C:\\Program Files\\Directories v0.6")
os.chdir("C:\\")
shutil.rmtree("C:\\dtmp")

print getpass.getuser()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bb-freeze-script.py", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('bbfreeze==0.97.3', 'console_scripts', 'bb-freeze')()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bbfreeze-0.97.3-py2.7-win32.egg\bbfreeze\__init__.py", line 24, in main
    f.addScript(x)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bbfreeze-0.97.3-py2.7-win32.egg\bbfreeze\freezer.py", line 410, in addScript
    s = self.mf.run_script(path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bbfreeze-0.97.3-py2.7-win32.egg\bbfreeze\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 241, in run_script
    co = compile(file(pathname, READ_MODE).read()+'\n', pathname, 'exec')
  File "C:\dtmp\main.py", line 14
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Operating system -- Windows XP

Comment: Something appears wrong in your main.py script (an indentation error). Can you post the code?

Comment: Yes, this is error in main.py script

Comment: Code: import os, sys

class Directory():
 def Create(self):
  dir = raw_input("Folder name: ")
  os.mkdir(dir)
  print "Created"
 def Delete(self):
  dir = raw_input("Folder name: ")
  os.rmdir(dir)
  print "Deleted"  def exit():

Comment: FYI, it would be nicer/better/more good to write your freezer script as a Python module callable from the command line, since then you could `import bb_freeze` and use an API which you would write in there. Calling Python code from Python code shouldn't really be done through `os.system`.

Comment: You shouldn't use backslashes in paths (forward slashes work on **all** systems including Windows). If you want to keep them, at least use raw strings (´r'C:\something'´) instead of escaping orgies (´'C:\\something'´)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a quick walkthrough on how to read tracebacks. It's pretty easy.

- Looking through your code, all of it is calling Python builtin modules. It's safe to say they're not causing the error, so the only thing left is the `os.system` call. Sure enough, you're calling `python` through said call (why would you not just import the module you want to call?).
- The traceback confirms that the error is in the other Python you are calling:

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "bb-freeze-script.py", line 8, in <module>
      load_entry_point('bbfreeze==0.97.3', 'console_scripts', 'bb-freeze')()
  ```
- Next, read through the lines of the transcript to burrow through the call stack and find out exactly where the error occurred.

  ```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bbfreeze-0.97.3-py2.7-win32.egg\bbfreeze\__init__.py", line 24, in main
      f.addScript(x)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bbfreeze-0.97.3-py2.7-win32.egg\bbfreeze\freezer.py", line 410, in addScript
      s = self.mf.run_script(path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bbfreeze-0.97.3-py2.7-win32.egg\bbfreeze\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 241, in run_script
      co = compile(file(pathname, READ_MODE).read()+'\n', pathname, 'exec')
  ```
- until you get to

  ```
  File "C:\dtmp\main.py", line 14
  IndentationError: expected an indented block
  ```

There you go, the error is in line 14 of `main.py`, where you should have had an indent but didn't.

Comment: +1 for teaching how to fish rather than simply serving dinner.